# Transistor's Input Current

Tags: transistors, current, resistors, bjt

This circuit is shown without coupling capacitors and source, which means I am referring only to DC.

If I define Ib1 (Q1) with voltage divider, so that Ic1 (Q1) equals 10mA and Ib2 (Q2) equals 5 mA:

- Will the 10mA current be flowing into the base of Q2 or the 5mA current?
- Or will 10mA current be flowing into the R4 and differential base-emitter resistance + Re2 ?
- Should Ic1=Ib2 ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXRujm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It does nothing since you have no ground. It's just a bunch of connections sitting at Vcc.

Comment: Something is missing: the  ground, for instance, and I think also a wire might be missing on the bottom part.

Comment: even if gnd is added, answers are N,N,N  . Collector loads are all shunt (shared) with nothing in  series to Q2 . But then Rc1 is redundant or R3/4 are redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are asking how to design such a circuit.

You start with assigning approximate amplification factors to each stage. How you choose them depends on your application. Having the same for each stage is a good start. If your supply voltage is on the low end, you want to have more gain at the earlier stages than at the later.

You know what current flow you want to have at the second stage and you know the gain you want. The gain is approximately Rc2/Re2. The current flowing will be at most Vcc/(Re2+Rc2). These two equations give you the *upper* limit for Re2 and Rc2. You should choose them a bit smaller than that. How much smaller is depends on how much Collector-Emitter voltage you want to have. This depends on the voltage capability of the BJT and the power dissipation capability. The former is usually not the limiting factor, unless you are doing high power application, while the latter is. You should have an idea how large your output signal is. Add some margin to that (10-100%) and use that as your Vce. As a rule of thumb, do not go below 1V of Vbe. Then you can plug this into the above formlas again: A=Rc2/Re2 and Ib=(Vcc-Vce)/(Re2+Rc2). The only remaining thing left now is to set Vbe. This simply follows from what you've chosen as Re2 and Ic, as this defines the voltage over Re2. Vbe, or rather Vb2 (relative to GND) should be V_Re2 + V_be(Ic2), where V_be(Ic2) is the basis-emitter voltage to get Ic2 current. As a decent approximation you can choose 0.6V for this on silicon transistors.

Armed with that, you go to the first stage. Here we have an additional constraint: The output voltage has to be V_b2. First of all, I would leave out R3 and R4, at least at first, as they only complicate the circuit without giving you anything (beside lower impedance between the two stages). So we choose Rc1 with respect to Ic1 such that the voltage over Rc1 gives us the right V_b2. Now can choose Re1 to give us the right amplification. The last thing to do is to choose R1 and R2 such that you get the right V_b1 (similar to how it's done for V_b2). The current through R1 and R2 should be at least a few times I_b1 (use at least a factor 2, factor 10 is better), which you can calculate from Ib=Ic/beta.

As last step, you check whether the circuit fulfills all your requirements and whether there is anything weird (V_be, V_ce and such at too high or too low values) and adjust your circuit if it doesn't meet one of these.

Comment: Thank you for your precious time but this is not what I wanted to ask. It is how Ic1 flows into next transistor stage and/or through a voltage divider of Q2.

Comment: Oh.. sorry. I misunderstood. For that you start again at the back. Q2 needs Ib2=Ic2/beta base current to work properly. So it will be pulling this much out. The voltage at the base defines how much current flows through R3 and R4. This defines how much current must come from Rc1/Q1..... Just by applying Kirchhoff's law repetitively you can figure out how the current flows.

Comment: I was mostly interested in the last three sentences you wrote in the comment. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

> If I define Ib1 (Q1) with voltage divider, so that Ic1 (Q1) equals 10mA and Ib2 (Q2) equals 5 mA:

OK so lets assume you can do that... which you cant since there are no grounds here... and even then...

> •Will the 10mA current be flowing into the base of Q2 or the 5mA current?

You just said you set Ib2 up to be 5mA ?

> •Or will 10mA current be flowing into the R4 and differential base-emitter resistance + Re2 ?

Makes no sense under your setup conditions.

> •Should Ic1=Ib2 ?

How can they be if you set one up to be 10mA and the other 5mA?

Comment: Bah, you don't understand the question. I missed the ground, so what, and you all now seek for mistakes I made in my question and not how to properly answer it. Sad.

Comment: @Keno.. I'm just trying to help you understand how bad your question is... You need to completely rewrite it in a form that makes sense if you want a real answer.